# Selecting all text in textarea using Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

I am trying to select all text which is there in textarea of pine script. [pinescript
image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlkA7.png)

So for that I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@class='ace_text-input']").send_keys(keys.CONTROL + "a")
```

the above is the only code which is relatable, my python code will open chrome go to https://in.tradingview.com/chart/ and wait for 2 mins and then click on Pine Editor and then

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@class='ace_text-input']").send_keys(keys.CONTROL + "a")
```

But, it's not getting selected and no errors showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [ActionChains](https://www.google.com/search?q=ctrl%2Ba%20action%20chain%20in%20python%20site%3Astackoverflow.com)

```
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("a").perform()
```